# How to compare std::string and TCHAR* in an if statement?

Tags: c++, string, tchar

I'm new at C++ coding, and I have this code:

```
std::string user_name = "raso";

// User Name 
TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN + 1;

GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &username_len);

if (user_name == username)
{
    std::cout << "You found the user name!";
}
```

It gives me an error. It basically finds the user name of the PC and compares it with the string `user_name`, but `user_name` is a `std::string` and `username` is a `TCHAR*` type, right? So, how can I compare both in an `if` statement?

Comment: `TCHAR` is a macro that expands either to `char` *or* `wchar_t`. Those two types are not compatible.

Comment: Note that `TCHAR` is a macro that expands to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on compilation settings.  `GetUserName` is also a macro that expands to `GetUserNameA` or `GetUserNameW` again depending on compilation settings.  WinAPI support both ANSI (code-page) or UNICODE (UTF-16) character-sets.  Given this is 2023 you should avoid ANSI and use UNICODE; unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: is there a way to make it on code?

Comment: @CodexSC `(TCHAR*)username` -- **Never** typecast string types.  Either use the proper string type, or use a function that accepts the string type you have.  If you must typecast, you better know exactly what you're doing.  All you did with your code when you casted is to tell the compiler "Stop complaining, I know what I'm doing".  If you removed that typecast, I am sure the compiler gave you an error -- please read the error that is given to you, as it indicates you are doing something wrong.  Also, typecasting strings does not convert strings from one type to another.

Comment: ... The cast is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix-and-match wide and narrow strings.

If your target name is `std::string`, use an `A` version of API: [GetUserNameA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea)

Also, your type casting `(TCHAR*)username` was not needed.

```
std::string user_name = "raso";

// User Name 
char username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN;

GetUserNameA(username, &username_len);

if (user_name == username)
{
    std::cout << "You found the user name!";
}
```

Comment: Hello! so how i can edit the code? can you show it on the code? sorry im a little noob

Comment: Ohhh i finally got it :D Thanks worked!

Comment: @CodexSC If you want to use `TCHAR`, then use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead of `std::string`, eg: `std::basic_string<TCHAR> user_name = TEXT("raso");` Then the original code would have worked.